# CLR Error - 80004005 while runing caspol command

Tags: .net, clr, caspol

I have tried to run Caspol command .I got CLR 80004005 error.I have re installed all versions of frameworks but in vain.Could any one help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Run it in an elevated command window. That error is indicating that you don't have permission.

Comment: Note 0x80004005 is E_FAIL ("Unspecified error"), a pretty generic error, not specifically related to any access denied or permission error.